# How to retrieve a String from a tag element using Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

I use a Jsoup to get the Elements from a web:

```
Elements addresses = doc.select("address > div");
```

and the result is like this:

```
<address>
    <div>
    7135 S Kingery Hwy<br>Willowbrook, IL 60527
</div>
<div class="phone">
        (630) 288-6635
</div>
</address>
```

I have a hard time to retrieve the address from the  tag. I use a text() method:

```
for (Element address : addresses) {
    Log.i("addresses", address.text() );
}
```

and the result is:

```
7135 S Kingery Hwy Willowbrook, IL 60527
(630) 288-6635
```

How can I filter it to retrieve the address only and also replace br tag with newline? Expected result:

```
7135 S Kingery Hwy 
Willowbrook, IL 60527
```

Comment: Lol. The example HTML and the result part doesn't match. Your requirement gets through, but I think it is better to make them match.

Comment: :) I have copied the wrong line. Thanks.

Comment: address.child(0).text() doesn't do it?

Comment: child(0) gives me IndexOutOfException. Thanks anyway for the help. The answer below works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
    Elements addresses = doc.select("address > :not(div[class=phone])");
    for (Element address : addresses) {
        for (Node node : address.childNodes()) {
            if (node.nodeName().equals("br")) {
                continue;
            }
            String text = node.toString().trim();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
```